# Sencha sqlite example

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html, sencha-touch

I would like to see a decent example of a mobile web app using the Sencha framework with a client side DB accessed with SQLite. I'm currently digesting JqTouch and kinda get the binding method used there from reading Jonathon Stark's "iPhone apps" book, but cant find any examples of accessing Senchas features ie listed elements with SQLite. The DB will be small; 30 records, with about 5 fields, mostly numeric, a few of them calculated. All the math is done in javascript and I have that part working (in dash code). I need to add, delete, and edit the records.

Any pointers or examples would be very much appreciated. I'm an old dog trying to learn new tricks. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sencha is client-side Javascript, so your application actually runs on top of Safari. That means you can forget about accessing (or installing) your own SQLite database from within the browser sandbox.

Having said that, you want to learn some new tricks, so why dont you read up on [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) and [DOM Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage). Basically the **HTML5 specification** allows for offline **database storage based on SQLite** (imagine relational database cookies). There is 1 per domain and they can be up to 5MB in size. I believe the iPhone supports this as well.

[image: HTML5 Database Functionality in iPhone]

Here are some links: [Introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/atcrabtree/local-storage) some [API Information](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH3-SW1) and a nice little [blog entry](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/) by a chap called Ben Lister

Answer (score 0):

Your client side code (i.e. Sencha/Javascript) would not access the SQLLite database.  It will either need to read JSON or XML from the server.  You'll need server side code to read the data from the database and format it in a way that your Sencha data readers will understand.

What are you using server side?  If it's PHP you should look into [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_sqlite/)

Answer (score 0):

I had very good experience integrating [Lawnchair](https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair) library with Sencha Touch. Take a look at their guide, it's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha's local storage doesn't take advantage of SQLite via the JavaScript API in the browser, but does use local key:value storage and has it's own way of referencing data to make it pseudo relational.  This is still part of the WebDB spec, which is probably still SQLite under the hood if I had to guess.  It's more persistent than a cookie or session, regardless.

You can also receive XML/JSON from a server over JSONP or Ajax if you're on the same domain, create a model to handle that data as well and bind it to a local store so that your data is available offline.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would help your points immensely if you could include references to your claims.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a SQLite proxy available for sencha 2 now.  http://market.sencha.com/addon/sqliteproxy-

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195991-SQLite-Proxy-for-ST2-%28advanced%29) on the Sencha Forums - it's a user created proxy for SQLite which I've successfully used to put data into a SQLite DB. The proxy comes with an example, but I might try and make a slightly more complicated one at some point.