# Large Offline Storage with Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sencha-touch, local-storage

I'm currently working on a mobile app (implemented using Sencha Touch 2 and designed to run on an iPad). There is a requirement to pull a fairly large amount of data (3000+ objects, objects have around 30 fields) down to the app from a web service and then persist the data locally for use offline. I've investigated the standard solutions discussed [here](https://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/) and elsewhere whereby localstorage proxies are used to persist the data after pulling it from the web service, but I run into the dreaded QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR due to the amount of data I'm trying to persist.

There are a handful of threads around discussing things like SQLLite and Lawnchair (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712921/sencha-sqlite-example) thread where someone mentions integrating Sencha with Lawnchair and refers to a guide which I can't find anywhere) but no concrete examples or success stories. Can anyone recommend a tried/tested method of persisting large datasets using Sencha Touch?

**EDIT**: After asking a similar question [on the Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205461-Large-Offline-Storage-with-Sencha-Touch-2&p=803975#post803975) I'm investigating the use of SQLite using the [SQLite Proxy for ST2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195991-SQLite-Proxy-for-ST2-%28advanced%29). Will update this thread further for the benefit of others once I have made progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up using the [SQLite Proxy for ST2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195991-SQLite-Proxy-for-ST2-%28advanced%29) to solve my problem regarding persistence of a large dataset. Highly recommended, and with a really helpful community on the Sencha forums who were invaluable in getting the solution working.