# How to use Sqlite in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: json, sqlite, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

How can we use sqlite with sencha touch 2 for storing data in json coming from server??

Is there any samples on it??

Comment: see if this is useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712921/sencha-sqlite-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an existing sencha touch proxy but tomalex0 has made a sqlLite proxy.

https://github.com/tomalex0/SenchaTouch-v2-SqliteProxy

You can also try and port the ExtJS version to Sencha Touch